# How do I use Freemarker when adding HTML in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, freemarker

I am using JavaScript to add HTML to my DOM. I want to include Freemarker in this, but it doesn't seem to work, it just becomes a string. Is there any way to do this?

I am using JavaScript to build a table based on the response from my Ajax-call. But I get information that I want to include in the table from two places, both from the Ajax-call and from a Freemarker template. I import the Freemarker template in the top of my HTML-file. And then try to do this in my JavaScript:

```
rows += '<td class=""><#if data.price?has_content>${data.price?number?string(",##0.00##")} ${otherData.currency!""}<#else>&#8211;</#if></td>';
```

I expect to get what I would get if I included it in my HTML-file directly, but instead it just becomes a string. Any ideas on another way to do it, or why it doesn't work?

Answer (score 1):

FreeMarker templates are executed on the server side. The browser just gets back the output of the template, it doesn't see any FreeMarker markup (and it couldn't understand it anyway). The basic idea of FreeMarker is to generate output based on information available on the server, without round trips between the client an the server.